# Add back link to activities somewhere in the new top bar

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

I find myself constantly going through my most recents comments, to see if people responded to them (but maybe didn't `@mention` me) or to see if there are any updates in general.

The previous bar had a dropdown with a link to my activities (taken from [this (related) question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207456/142802)):

> [image]

Could we please integrate a link to activities somehow/somewhere in the bar or in one of the  dropdowns?

Having to go to my profile first, waiting for it to load and then click on the activity tab is really time consuming.

---

If we don't want to add such a link because most users don't actually use it, how about adding it for high rep users, to increase (or rather keep) their level of productivity?

Comment: It would appear that the testing done found very few people actually using that link, hence it's removal.

Comment: +1, but Rep gains are displayed in the Inbox now.  The other activity stuff is also available on your profile page.

Comment: I only care about a "quick link" to activities. I know that I can go through my profile, but it's annoying.

Comment: @Servy: How was the testing conducted? I consider myself as a *very* active user and I use it all the time. I assume that most users are not as active as me. If we don't want to show such a link to every user, then at least for high rep users?

Comment: @Felix I used it all the time too. Aside from that, it's nice to see the week/month totals..

Comment: @Felix I don't know how they did the testing, although I'm not particularly surprised that it's not commonly used.  You're one active user that seems to use it regularly.  There are many thousands of other users; it would need to be a large percentage of them to really justify adding the link.

Comment: @JoshC That's an entirely different feature that this post isn't talking about...

Comment: @Servy: I can understand that the UI should be optimized for "typical" users. However, if this cripples the "productivity" of highly active users, it might be a disadvantage for the site in the long run.

Comment: @Felix I wouldn't consider one extra click to get to a given page "crippling".  Also, you haven't even shown that most "highly active" users would use this link, let alone use it frequently.  I consider myself highly active and I never used it once.

Comment: @Servy: You wouldn't know if you don't actually used that link ;)

Comment: I really miss that link too, as I use it a lot to go back to questions I had commented, answered, edited, or reviewed in the past.

Comment: @Felix I'd like to think that I've used the internet enough to have some idea of how much work is involved in clicking a link...One's pretty much the same as the next.

Comment: @Servy One Click vs Two Clicks may be almost the same if the links are in the same spot, but One Click > Wait for Page Load > Move Mouse Across Screen > Second Click is nowhere near the same as One Click :)

Comment: @Rachel I didn't say that it was; I just said that it wasn't "crippling".

Comment: +1: I also found that link useful.

Comment: @Servy: Maybe you just have a different workflow. I really rely on that link and it slows me down when I want to jump between posts, get updated and provide updates. I assume I'm not the only one who does that. I understand your point, but please try to understand mine. I don't believe that adding the link back could have any *negative* impact on "normal" users, but it potentially has a *positive* impact on very active users (it certainly has for me).

Comment: All menus have dropdowns, minus our user's menu... :(

Comment: I'm going crazy without the activity link. I used it dozens of times a day. Please bring it back.

Answer (score 15):

I would really, really, love this to return. It was my most clicked link on the entire network!

I use comments to remember what questions I need to go back and check. To see if an OP has replied, without actually replying or to generally find posts that I remember seeing previously. Instead of a little hover and a small swerve of the mouse I now have to:

1. Move mouse to top of screen
2. Wait for hover to work
3. Remember that it doesn't work any more and click my username.
4. Move mouse almost to the bottom of the page.
5. Click activity

Here my pointer-moving-and-clicking-heroics stop, because the sub-tab(?) I was previously browsing in the activity tab is remembered.

Which brings me to my "second best" suggestion. If it's decided not to add this back in, how about you [remember me?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5pAOHwcd4c&t=2m19s). Remember the higher-level tabs that I use the whole time and send me back there as a default.

[image: Me]

I don't mind clicking to see my accepts (I don't think I ever have) but the tabs I use constantly should be the ones I'm defaulted to.

Comment: Good alternative suggestion and nice description of your workflow. I'd also argue that it was one of my most clicked links.

Comment: I've been thinking about this since [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207614/179419) @Felix! I'd prefer it to return but if it can't this is all I can think of.

Comment: If they do choose to use this alternative, can they be sure the problem with the [Back button loading old data on the Activity page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176298/158605) gets fixed?

Comment: I wish to believe that they added the link in the first place [because I asked for it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82894/142802) (I don't know though). I really like that link.