# How to get my hover-menu back?

Tags: feature-request, support, tooltips, top-bar

What happened with the menu that comes if I hover over my username in the top-bar? It was one of the most used feature on Stackoverflow since I've used it regularly to get a quick overview over my recent activities or reputation changes.

Is it possible to get it back somehow?

[image: Hover-Menu]

Comment: Partial duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209963/add-back-link-to-activities-somewhere-in-the-new-top-bar?rq=1. The rep you can see on the left... if you click.

Comment: hover-menu's  are soooo 2013

Comment: Apparently it was removed because touch based users could not hover. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207456/178816 . Link shows this request as the top voted answer for when the bar was being beta'd on meta.

Comment: I cannot believe this new bar went live without this. It was complained about in several locations with large amounts of upvotes. The hover *needs* to come back.

Comment: Yes, i have seen those questions but the beta link is locked now and the "partial" duplicate is not about the hover-menu in general.

Comment: I'm kind of curious about where `privileges` and `log out` are located now.

Comment: I had finally gotten used to the Hover menu too...

Comment: Same here, and also my `meta` link. I have to click twice to get to meta, no!!!

Comment: @MichaelT Logout is in the main menu (you know, the one with all the sites). The privileges can be accessed via help>help center, as well as a lot of other useful links that weren't featured in the previous design.

Comment: @Sumurai8 thank you.  That also helps with the identification on how to link to it - [help/privileges] (hmm - apparently can't link that that way? Well, still have the long link form).

Comment: @MichaelT The log out link is on the site collider, the privileges list is in the help center.

Comment: the hover/popup is the one i mostly used, i do like it. when will it comes back?

Comment: I'm not a designer so all I can tell about `Inbox` and `Achievements` drop downs is that they look plain and ugly, probably rendered with default styles from some generic jQuery component. A clear step backwards!

Comment: Touch based users are frankly starting to annoy me.  This is just the latest in a series of UI casualties where designers have wrecked previously excellent interfaces to cater to fumble-thumbs and greasy-paws.  There should be a padded version of the internet for people who want to use crippled devices.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few steps to reproduce your favorite popout. Who knows how long it will be around server side though. The styling is from a [user script](https://github.com/travisjj/SE-LightSide).

[image: hover-menu]

#1 Simple js

```
//Everyone's favorite hover
$('.profile-me').children(":first").addClass('profile-link');
var d = StackExchange.helpers.DelayedReaction(function () {
 profileLink.show()
}, 450, { always: function () {
 j.cancel() }
});
var j = StackExchange.helpers.DelayedReaction(function () {
 profileLink.hide()
}, 1E3, { always: function () {
 d.cancel() }
});
$('.profile-link').mouseenter(d.trigger);
$('.profile-me').mouseleave(j.trigger);
```

#2 Might want some style

```
.profile-me .profile-popup{
 line-height: 25px;
 margin-top: 34px !important;
}
```

Comment: 1+ I'm using this now. Thanks Travis! A minor edit though, I changed `$('.reputation').css({fontWeight:'bold'});` to `$('.links-container > .reputation').css({fontWeight:'bold'});` There was actually a `.reputation` class on the profile pages that was being bolded.

Comment: @JoshC - Updated to include the bold adjustment :) Also, I slightly tuned the popout to use more SO exposed functionality for the popout menu that you may be interested in.

Comment: +1, this setting should go into user preferences.

Answer (score 5):

You can still access it until we kill it: https://stackoverflow.com/users/profile-link-stats

^ **It's not supported and does not have a stylesheet**

Comment: Hey, at least make the page way better designed so we don't have to avert our eyes when looking at it.

Comment: @hichris123 If any changes are made at all, it'd almost certainly be to just remove it, given that it's no longer used...

Comment: @Servy That's true, also too much of a pain to get to vs. the new way.

Comment: That's fine by me, as long as **you don't kill it until you provide a functionally equivalent replacement**.

Comment: Anything we can do to delay its killing?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd and Gilles: See my comment on an unrelated answer (makes sense here too) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209906/eeeek-hot-network-questions-killed-recent-tags-and-recent-badges/209908#comment672462_209908

Comment: @Sklivvz The lack of hover menu (and specifically of the [day's vote count](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2543/give-me-an-easy-way-to-see-my-daily-vote-count)) is making me [freeze](http://xkcd.com/1172/). Maybe it wasn't used by a lot of people (but how would you know which parts of the hover thingy people were reading?), but for some of us, it was very useful.

Comment: I refuse to believe that current Inbox and Achievements drop downs are made **by the same person** who did hover-menu. It is a matter of no taste vs. clean and appealing design.

Answer (score 2):

The new top bar was designed with the goal of simplifying and bringing forward things that 90% of our users are interested in, and then we took a second pass looking at this from our very active users to make sure that we weren't screwing up your workflow.

Basically, we determined that nobody was using the week and month columns and the revisions and favorites rows didn't make sense. There was a lot of discussion around the votes cast... It appeared to be used infrequently, but it looks like it was a few users using it frequently instead of a lot of users using it infrequently.

The menu isn't coming back, but I think the activity link and votes cast today are legitimate gripes that I'd like to work with you to see if we can come up with another solution.

I'm roughly considering either making the achievements header link directly to the activity tab or renaming the achievements drop-down to activity and having the same behavior.

With respect to votes cast, I'd like to find someplace else to put that.

Comment: One of the reasons I enjoy the hover menu is the quick access to recent activity. I like to review my posts, especially if they have been recently voted on. This is one of the fastest ways to get there. I also like how the breakdown in the hover menu shows only by site, which is nice if you are curious about the current site you are on and not your exchange wide activity.For example, 5 posts ago in the current site can get lost in the achievements dropdown, but the hover menu will show it.It saves me a trip to my profile summary page and detective work to determine which posts I should review.

Comment: As the person who votes the most and used the hover menu constantly, your last idea (notification after you vote when you only have a few votes left) already happens and doesn't provide the necessary information.  I'm working on a feature-request question with some better ideas...

Comment: I kind of like renaming "achievements" to "activities" but that's mostly because I don't like the term "achievements". Unfortunately renaming it like that would overload the definition of "activity" since the Activity tab on the user profile does something completely different from what's shown in the dropdown.

Comment: "we determined that nobody was using the week and month columns". How do you determine that? If the menu pops up, you can't track my eye movements (... or?). I always checked my monthly track record to keep myself going (one of the incentives to contribute to the site).