# I want my vote hover/popup back on the top bar!

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

I don't mind the new top bar, but when the new topbar was tested on meta.SO, it was widely requested to include the popup window that used to show up when you hovered over the username.

(In case it's not clear, I'm talking about the popup window that used to show day/month/year Votes cast, Reputation changes, etc.)

I particularly miss the daily vote count, it's a huge hassle for me to check how many times I've voted on a day, I have to go to my profile page and usually wait for some caching to catch up.

Even though I've been reading meta.SO every day, I haven't seen anything about adjustments being made to the new topbar based on feedback there, so I thought I'd post here.

If there's anything else you don't like about the new top bar, feel free to include it in an answer or a separate post.  I don't think SE staff will actually pay attention, but you never know...

Comment: Related: [How to get my hover-menu back?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209988/how-to-get-my-hover-menu-back)

Comment: I think the SE staff do not like it so it will be vetoed.  I don't like that they are not listening to us. I am not keen on the rest, but can live with it.  But I do want the 'hover/popup' back.

Comment: I'm unsurprised to see you [wanting the daily vote count](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2543/give-me-an-easy-way-to-see-my-daily-vote-count) too.

Comment: Related Feature Request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210260/include-vote-count-in-achievements-drop-down