# Include vote count in Achievements drop down

Tags: feature-request, voting, top-bar

Various SE staff have said [the hover popup is not coming back](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2543) and have suggested ["make a case for putting that information somewhere else."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209908/130540)  Ok, here are some thoughts and suggestions:

- Loss of the hover popup was the highest-voted complaint about the new top bar when it was tested on meta.
- Voting is a good thing on SE, and the people who vote the most across all SE sites used the vote count in the pop up constantly.  Since all other pages that show vote counts are cached, checking how many times you've voted now (usually) requires you to take a break and wait for the counts to update.

First idea (minimal solution) put "Votes Today" for the current site at the top of the Achievements drop-down.

Or: (better) make a new drop-down to go where the hover popup was (drops down when you click your Gravatar/rep/badges) that shows Votes cast (today and maybe week), reputation change and maybe changes in favourites.  UTC would make more sense in this new drop-down as well.

Comment: If you replace the click on the Gravatar/rep/badges, how will you get to your profile? Or how exactly were you thinking it should work?

Comment: @Dukeling I didn't think that far ahead... Maybe make clicking on the Gravatar give you the new dropdown I'm asking for and have a link on that dropdown that goes to your profile.

Answer (score 2):

I miss that hover tally too.

Profile pages now show your vote counts for the day, week, and month, along with totals.  It's not ideal because you have to go to your profile (so click and scroll from where you had the hover tally), but it's not *that* far away.

[image: screenshot]

Further, for rationing purposes, when you get down to your last five votes of the day you get a pop-up notice when you vote.  (It's early in the day, so I don't have a screenshot for you.)

Comment: Unless something's changed, though, those vote counts are heavily cached, which makes them useless for this.  On ServerFault, for example, the counts have sometimes shown what they were on the *previous* day.  There's a question specifically about the vote counts being extremely out of date, but I can't look for it right now.