# Reliable count of votes that I've cast today

Tags: feature-request, voting, user-interface, top-bar, caching

I often want to know how many votes (upvotes and downvotes) I've cast today, so as to know how far I am from the 40 vote limit.

In the old days, this information was easily accessible on each page by [hovering over my name in the top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/feedback-request-new-top-bar-and-multicollider-redesign/199634#199634). Sadly, this information [disappeared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207461#207461). I now have to load my profile page in a separate tab and scroll down near the bottom, a marked regression in user experience.

To add injury to insult, this number is cached. I can't easily know how many votes I've cast, only how many votes I had cast as of an unspecified number of minutes ago. I've observed the cache to last more than one hour! The only reliable way to know how many votes I've cast (assuming no post that I voted on was deleted) is to switch to the activity tab of my profile and count the entries for today in the upvotes and downvotes subtabs. Yeech.

Please fix this significant user interface regression. Provide **easy** access to a **reliable** daily vote count (either the number cast so far, or the number I have left).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include vote count in Achievements drop down](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210260/include-vote-count-in-achievements-drop-down)

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, that's different. My primary complaint here is about the caching. I also don't consider access through the achievements dropdown an easy way, given that I've hidden it to avoid the jarring constant spam notifications.

Comment: Aside: thanks to the keyboard shortcut `R`, achievements can be accessed easily even when hidden. But I agree this is not a dupe, since the emphasis of this request is different.

Comment: Those of us who vote the most REALLY want this.  Especially since the profile page is so heavily cached it's showing me *yesterday's* vote count! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239887/caching-should-not-show-me-yesterdays-info

Comment: I have the feeling that this is somewhat intertwined to [the bizarre way the daily vote limit works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90256/255554). Moreover, due to this, not knowing one’s number of votes is an additional annoyance (see [this feature request of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244211/255554)).

Comment: Yeah, this is still hurting me every day.  I'm constantly *counting* my votes!

Comment: @Ward Fortunately Normal Human's script works well, as long as you have it installed in your browser.

Comment: This is something we want to improve but will not work on at the moment.  When User Profiles are updated (coming soon) this will be reassessed since User Profiles is where this will likely go.

Answer (score 19):

Having lost the hope of SE doing anything about vote counts, I made a simple [bookmarklet](http://dropproxy.com/f/7FC#votes) that provides

> easy access to a reliable daily vote count

```
javascript:(function()%7Bs%3D%7B'upvote'%3A0%2C'downvote'%3A0%2C'deletion'%3A0%2C'undeletion'%3A0%2C'closure'%3A0%2C'reopen'%3A0%7D%3Bm%3Dtrue%3Bd%3Dnew Date().getUTCDate()%3Bp%3Dnew DOMParser()%3Bw%3Ddocument.querySelector('.profile-me').href%2B'%3Ftab%3Dvotes%26sort%3Dall%26page%3D'%3Bj%3D1%3Bwhile (m) %7Bu%3Dw%2Bj%2B%2B%3Br%3Dnew XMLHttpRequest()%3Br.onload%3Df%3Br.open('get'%2Cu%2Cfalse)%3Br.send()%3B%7Da%3D%5B'up%2Fdown%3A '%2Cs.upvote%2Bs.downvote%2C'%5Cr%5Cnup%3A '%2Cs.upvote%2C'%5Cr%5Cndown%3A '%2Cs.downvote%2C'%5Cr%5Cnclose%3A '%2Cs.closure%2C'%5Cr%5Cndelete%3A '%2Cs.deletion%2C'%5Cr%5Cnreopen%3A '%2Cs.reopen%2C'%5Cr%5Cnundelete%3A '%2Cs.undeletion%5D%3Bwindow.alert(a.join(''))%3Bfunction f(e) %7Bx%3Dp.parseFromString(e.currentTarget.responseText%2C'text%2Fhtml')%3Bv%3Dx.querySelector('.history-table').firstElementChild.children%3Bfor (i%3D0%3Bi<v.length%3Bi%2B%2B) %7Bif (v%5Bi%5D.querySelector('.date').title.substring(8%2C10)%3D%3Dd) %7Bs%5Bv%5Bi%5D.children%5B1%5D.textContent.split('(')%5B0%5D.trim()%5D%2B%2B%3B%7Delse %7Bm%3Dfalse%3B%7D%7D%7D%7D)()
```

It loads and parses the profile tab *votes/all* (multiple pages if needed), and presents the counts in plain  alert window. Should work from any page of the site (question lists, question pages, etc).

[image: stats]

Tested in Chrome and Firefox. The up/down counts do not include votes on deleted posts, which I like since votes on deleted posts do not count toward 40 vote limit.

Comment: But the count on *votes/all* is also cached, so this doesn't reliably show current votes.

Comment: It updates quickly for me. I just tested this by running the bookmarklet, then voting, then running it again within the same minute. Maybe there are some seconds of delay. Or maybe your experience is different because there's something up with Server Fault voting database specifically. Not enough disk space or something (and you are to blame, of course).