# Caching should not show me yesterday's info!

Tags: bug, voting, caching

I know the answer is always "caching" whenever the question is about inconsistent data, but this is ridiculous:

I've cleared my browser cache, but when I look at my user profile on Server Fault, at the bottom I see:

> [image: votes]

But those are my voting stats as of 12 hours ago, when I last looked at them on this laptop!  A new day (in UTC) has started, but I'm still seeing my "day" votes from yesterday!  And as you can see from this display of weekly votes:

> [image: wrong]

Today's 60 votes aren't showing up yet.  As I said, I know it's because of caching, but I really don't think these #s should be cached for this long, especially since this is the only place to see how many votes you've cast today.

UPDATE: This has never been fixed, so the "day" column of Votes Cast might as well not be there since it's currently showing me (on ServerFault) my vote count as of 2 days ago!

It's pointed out in a comment that the Votes tab is the only way to be sure how much you've voted today, but that's a bit ridiculous because you have to count them yourself - the total isn't correct because it doesn't doesn't include votes on deleted posts.

Why is it impossible to get an accurate count of how many votes someone has cast in a day/week/whatever?

Comment: Yes, looks like someone over-optimized user profile stats. (The /votes tab shows current information, however). Related: [Reliable count of votes that I've cast today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239601).

Comment: How did you manage to spend 60 votes on a day?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft  I'm not sure I want to share my secret...

Comment: About your edit: The reason the count is much lower on the /votes tab is that it excludes the votes on deleted posts. Notably, those votes are also excluded from the daily vote cap. So, using the data from /votes was, and remains, the only way to know how many votes you have left for the day.

Answer (score 5):

I know that SE use very aggressive caching on *their* side as well, so my guess is that this data is stale in their cache, but for some reason is not triggering a refresh of their stale cache.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely caching on SE's end... I just checked with Firefox, which I never use, and I see the same out of date data.