# Menu to show daily progress towards vote / flag limits

Tags: feature-request, flags, voting, top-bar

I want to track how many of what (regular votes, comment votes, close votes, delete votes, flags, etc... excluding review actions) I have left throughout the day. I find I often will run out of one of these things because I haven't paced myself properly. Unfortunately, it can get hard to pace yourself if you don't have an easy way to find this information.

Sure it shows me how many close votes and flags I have left in their respective dialogs, and when my regular votes are getting low it will notify me (too late IMO) of this fact. Voting on comments just runs out without any warning.

It would be nice if I could find this information all in one place. I would just write a userscript, but it seems like the benefit of having all of this information in one place wouldn't outweigh the overhead of all of the requests necessary to get all of this information.

[image]

I got as far as the icon, I haven't gotten around to creating a mock-up of what I think the menu should look like, but the idea in my head is a list of progress bars with the number of actions left (or actions done so far, whichever makes more sense) versus the limit for that action.

Another helpful thing to have here would be a `?` with a tooltip for each action explaining why those numbers are the way they are, mainly to help avoid frequently asked questions on those topics (but also because we all love helpful tooltips)

Obviously only the actions that you can do should be shown, and this might be a good place for the badge progress indicators that were recently experimented with.

Comment: The other option is to write a userscript that tracks actions done / undone, but that comes with its own problems.

Comment: "I should put up a FR for an inventory page - I sometimes wonder how many of a flag / vote I have left, and I'd have to find a random page and click buttons for that." [- me, Nov 13 '14](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=2654277#2654277)

Comment: Is there already a user script for this? I want it.

Comment: @Zizouz212 not that I know of.

Comment: *tears come out of eyes*.

Comment: I wonder how many people would upvote this... but ran out of votes for the day....

Comment: Could always start an upvoting campaign^

Comment: I use a [bookmarklet](http://normalhuman.github.io/stackmarklets/#votes) to track all types of post votes. Could be made a userscript; the source is there. I never run out of comment votes...

Comment: @MiceElf Cool, thanks. If this doesn't get implemented, I'll use that as the base for a userscript.

Comment: Partial duplicate of [Include vote count in achievements drop down](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210260/include-vote-count-in-achievements-drop-down).  It would be really handy to have this since [caching means there's nowhere you can reliably find your vote count.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239887/caching-should-not-show-me-yesterdays-info)

Comment: @Ward: Thanks for those. It looks like people have been wanting easy access to this information for quite some time.

Comment: I think the existing ways to check these things are quite sufficient. As you've admitted, when people are actually doing the things this list would measure, they're already told their vote amounts *in those places*; they don't really care about those numbers elsewhere. The only thing this request really adds (other than collation) is tracking comment voting, but comments are zealously pushed as temporary, transient, impermanent, etc., so I don't see them rushing to add more comment-related features.

Comment: I also wonder how many people actually run out of votes repeatedly, when not voting for the purpose of getting the Vox Populi badge. It's never happened to me, though I've come relatively close once or twice.

Comment: I would have to disagree as I think this would prompt people to use their votes more, and we want people to vote as much as they can right? @TylerH Also, I run out of all sorts of votes (and so do lots of people you know) on a regular basis.

Comment: @TinyGiant I was referring specifically to question (and comment) votes, for the record, and the group of users from the SOCVR room is hardly even a blip on the radar of total users to consider, to be honest, so I can't agree with the sentiment behind "lots of people I know".

Comment: Hey I run out of regular votes on a regular basis too. The point is that I want to know how many votes I have *before* voting so that I can better determine whether *that* post is worth my vote. @TylerH

Comment: @TinyGiant While I agree that an easier-to-check solution than [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/288751/tiny-giant?tab=votes) would indeed be helpful, I don't think an entirely new menu is necessary, because I don't think all those other things belong on it, either.

Comment: @TylerH The issue for [people like me or Gilles who regularly vote a lot](http://serverfault.com/users/6177/ward?tab=profile) is that caching makes _all_ the pages that show vote counts unreliable.